# Headless Wordpress Blog With Sveltekit Not Pulling Posts

Tags: wordpress, svelte, sveltekit, headless

I'm trying to use sveltekit to build a blog using headless wordpress. I was following along with [this app](https://github.com/kellenmace/intro-to-headless-wordpress-with-sveltekit), but I think it's outdated.

I think I figured out routing, but on my blog page, I keep getting No Posts Found even though there are a couple posts on my local Wordpress install. I'm also using the WPGraphQL interface to make sure the query is pulling the data.

+page.js

```js
const query = `
    query getPosts {
      posts {
        nodes {
          databaseId
          uri
          title
          excerpt
          date
          featuredImage {
            node {
              sourceUrl
              altText
              mediaDetails {
                width
                height
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }`;

export async function load({ fetch }) {
    const response = await fetch(import.meta.env.VITE_PUBLIC_WORDPRESS_API_URL, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }, body: JSON.stringify({ query }),
    });

    if (response.ok) {
        const responseObj = await response.json();
        const posts = responseObj.data.posts.nodes;

        return {
            props: {
                posts
            }
        };
    }

    return {
        status: response.status, error: new Error(`Could not load ${url}`)
    };
}
```

+page.svelte

```
<script>
    export let posts;
</script>

<h1>Blog</h1>
{#if posts}
    <ul>
        {#each posts as post}
            <li>
                {post.title}
            </li>
        {/each}
    </ul>
{:else}
    <p>No posts found.</p>
{/if}

<style>
    ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
    }
    ul li + li {
        margin-top: 2rem;
    }
</style>
```

I am really new at this and I am not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way the data is transferred is off. It should just be `return { posts }` and in the page all [data from the `load` function](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#page-data) is passed in a prop called `data`. So the posts would be in `data.posts`.

([For errors](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#errors) one should `throw` an error object constructed with the `error` function from `@sveltejs/kit` to show the `+error.svelte` page.)